# warning: it is defined but never used

Tags: reactjs

how to add a component to my react project 
I already defined it and import it in app js
but it did not work and the console tells me 
 **warning: it is defined but never used**

Comment: please add some code that we can look at

Answer (score 1):

That's not an issue. Your component is being exported and imported correctly.

The thing, you are importing a component but you didn't use that anywhere. That's what warning shows you. If you don't need that component to use, remove the import line for that component to remove the warning message from the console.

Or, if you use eslint, add the following comment just after the import statement

```
// eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

Or, you may configure with [more option](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars):

```
/*eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "vars": "local" }]*/
/*global some_unused_var */
```

Comment: i wanna use the component but i donot know make it work ?